# Heroku Deploy can't find devise-1.4.6

Tags: heroku, devise

Trying to deploy to Heroku but get the following error:

```
-----> Gemfile detected, running Bundler version 1.0.7
       Unresolved dependencies detected; Installing...
       Using --without development:test
       Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/
       Could not find devise-1.4.6 in any of the sources
       FAILED: http(preventing hyperlink)://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to install gems via Bundler
```

I have "gem 'devise'" in my gem file, have "source 'http://rubygems.org'" at the top, and have run both bundle install and bundle update.  Not sure why Heroku is looking for 1.4.6.  Any ideas?

Thanks!

John

Here is the gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.0.9'
gem 'devise'

gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.3', :group => :development
```

Looks like devise 1.4.6 is no longer at Rubygems.com: http://rubygems.org/gems/devise/versions

I tried using devise 1.4.5, but it didn't work either.

Comment: Are you able to post your full Gemfile?

Comment: source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.0.9'
gem 'devise'

gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.3', :group => :development

Comment: Heroku will be reading from your Gemfile.lock - what version does that show against devise?

Comment: I just retried it, checking the Gemfile.lock first, and it said 1.4.7 for devise, but I got the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update the locked version of Devise in your `Gemfile.lock`.

```
$ bundle update devise
```

Then commit, push and deploy to Heroku.

Comment: AHH, it was the commit step I was not taking after the update.  Thanks!