# Deploy on Heroku failed: Could not find devise-1.4.4 in any of the sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I follow a deploy article by [Getting Started with Heroku](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/quickstart).

I tried to deploy my app to heroku. At the beginning I had this problem

```
-----> Gemfile detected, running Bundler version 1.0.7
   Unresolved dependencies detected; Installing...
   Using --without development:test
   Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/
   Could not find devise-1.4.4 in any of the sources
   FAILED: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler
   Heroku push rejected, failed to install gems via Bundler
```

Then I tried some solutions, for example [heroku-deploy-cant-find-devise-1-4-6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7589223/heroku-deploy-cant-find-devise-1-4-6).
I followed these steps

```
bundle update 
git add .
git commit -a "please work"
git push heroku master
```

but it still have problem.
Here's my Gemfile

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
 gem 'rails', '3.0.9'  
 gem 'kaminari'
 gem "paperclip", "~> 2.4"
 gem "devise"
 gem 'web-app-theme', '>= 0.6.2'
 gem 'gmaps4rails'
 gem 'populator'
 gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.2.6'
 gem 'capistrano'
```

and Gemfile.lock

```
 ...
 capistrano-ext (1.2.1)
 capistrano (>= 1.0.0)
 cocaine (0.2.0)
 crack (0.3.1)
 devise (1.4.8)
  bcrypt-ruby (~> 3.0)
  orm_adapter (~> 0.0.3)
  warden (~> 1.0.3)
  ...
```

It seem to be good.

But why it still have the same problem.

```
Could not find devise-1.4.4 in any of the sources
```

Why my Gemfile.lock uses devise 1.4.8 but it still deploy devise-1.4.4? How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

[Devise 1.4.4 was yanked](https://rubygems.org/gems/devise/versions) on RubyGems, you need to use any version greater than 1.4.4.

You don't seem to use 1.4.4 in any source. Make sure to specify a version, otherwise other gems might force bundler to use the yanked version.

```
# Gemfile
gem "devise", "~> 1.4.8"
```

Then run

```
$ bundle update devise
```

Also, make sure the `Gemfile.lock` file is stored in your git repository. Otherwise Heroku will try to resolve the dependencies on its own. **Commit the changes**, then push to Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

try putting in your gemfile

gem "devise", "~> 1.4.4"

and then run bundle install before recommiting

Comment: from my understanding of ~> it will drop the last number and use the latest version. So ~> 1.4.4 will use the latest version up until 1.4.9    http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/16#page74 has more info about the version selectors.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like one of your other gems is requiring devise 1.4.4, which was yanked from rubyforge. Check your gemfile.lock for any other mentions of devise under other gems.

Just to eliminate any other possible funny business, try this in your gemfile:

```
gem "devise", "1.4.8"
```

And then running:

```
bundle update devise
git commit
git push heroku master
```

Comment: Thanks for your help ,I try this metod but it still have problem

Answer (score 0):

I try stupid and complicated method, but work for me.
I git my project into Github before.
So I try my former codes which didn't have FB plugin.(maybe it was rfacebook problem !?)

```
mkdir test-for-another-sol
cd test-for-another-sol
git init 
git pull git@github.com:your_name/your_git.git  feature/your_former_project
bundle update devise 
git add .
git commit -a "please work"
git push git@heroku.com:your_app_in_heroku.git master
```

It work!